# Bootstrap: full width dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to do full width dropdown menu but dropdown menu items should be strictly below the menu item (with right: 0). Display: table like in other examples here on stackoverflow didn't help me.
Please, advice me what I can do with this.

Comment: Please show you html or produce a fiddle

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/j1V2QwUAKu1CSYjZA4ti?p=preview

Comment: I wanted <li> placed like this and full width <ul>. Or <div> as next sibling of <ul> with full width.

Comment: You're completely overriding the way the Bootstrap dropdown works using display: flex etc so this question isn't really about the Bootstrap dropdown

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you want the `ul.dropdown-menu` to have `100%` width as the `home-topmenu`

to do that, one solution would be to make the `ul.dropdown-menu` to be `absolute` relative to the `.home-topmenu` .

so you must add `position:relative` to `.home-topmenu` and remove `position:relative` form `div.dropdown`

then add `width:100%` to `ul.dropdown-menu` and position it how you want.

let me know if this helps.

Comment: well. why not ? i made those changes in your plnkr and it works. can you be more specific ? and please use the SO snippet to show your problem or at least a jsfiddle

Comment: please read my answer correctly. REMOVE `position:relative` from  `.dropdow` and ADD it to `.home-topmenu` , plus other css styles that i wrote in my answer. also. don't use plnkr. it's very hard to work/edit it. use SO snippet or at least jsfiddle